# "Not Enough Space" when using RestForce to get the Metadata of Account object

Tags: rest-api, metadata, python

Im Using a developer account, just created to Test retrieve and deploy Metadata using RESTFORCE.

```
r.get('data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/describe/')
```

the above line throws that error. the get request which returns the JSON format dosent throw this error, i have updated restForce code to return the XML format. During which im facing the "Not Enough Space" error.. is this my local system error or is it from Salesforce. Please help me find the workaround. Also let me know if any more related info is needed to solve this.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ERROR Errno::12 Not enough space` is a generic error which appears when your Java/ Ruby apps run out of memory. I'd recommend checking

- If your host/ VM has run out of memory while executing your program
- If your sessions are never getting expired or killed or there's something else which is hogging memory and not releasing it
- Check if you are using the supported versions of Rails

I've used Restforce earlier without any issues. If you think this is a bug, I'd recommend raising an issue [here](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce/issues).

Comment: Thanks, Gaurav. i ran this code using the KOMODO IDE, in which the space ran out and led to this error. tnx for narrowing it down